Include configuration to snakemake report when using --configfile
I'd like to have my SnakeMake configuration included in my report HTML file.
I found this SO question that has the same request, but in my use-case I provide the config-file using the cmdline interface using --configfile. The answer on that question  does not get desired result. The report I generate from a completed run does not include a configuration tab. So, how do I get my configuration included?

Does your snakefile have configfile:  somehere in it? It should. According to Snakemake's best practices, "Configuration of a workflow should be handled via config files ..." . Snakemake’s CLI arguments are just meant for runtime specific configuration. And according to Snakemake's 'standard-configuration' maybe you are creating an empty array and that is why the configuration toggle is not shown? "If the configfile statement is not used, the config variable provides an empty array. ... "  ...

 (Maybe it has to be a setting in the snakefile for the report to include it and --configfile argument isn't enough to trigger it. I'd test it if I had more time.) I suspect you can actually have the configfile:  setting in the snakefile match the argument you pass in via --configfile on the command line. I think I could parse it via Python, alas maybe snakemake already has this accessible more conveniently. I'd test this if I had more time, too. Since these are just ideas to try and directions to troubleshoot, I'll probably delete it all if better ideas show up.

@Wayne I did add configfile: f"{workflow.basedir}/../Config/Config.yaml" in my Snakefile and it did not change the outcome..

Thanks for trying that. It seems to contradict the documentation then, right? Does that work to make it if it you remove --configfile item from the command? Or is something generally wrong with configuration? I tried searching for a related issue report here; however, I am not seeing anything obvious.

I tried that, but then the whole pipeline starts to rerun all steps and they are quite computationally intensive. So I'd rather not do that and had to kill it. I had expected more response, as the SnakeMake website is referring to SO for questions. Should I make it a feature request on the issues page then?

You could make a toy snakemake pipeline and try the testing with that not & on something that is computationally intense. ... I cannot advise best way to proceed. Maybe if your tests conclusively don't match the documentation it would warrant an issue report.
